# Golang doesn't recompile some file

Tags: go, build, compilation

I just got an error:

## server

server/server.go:73: undefined: foo.MyName

I didn't understand at first and I tried to change the name of my function etc..
So I created a function called MyName() which return a string which is my name..

But, the error just came up again.. After more than one hour, I just tried to comment all of my code in the package foo ! I wanted to say f**k that at this moment... #PS: I also comment the server.go:73 line.. and.. It compiles and totally works?!

I commented my code, but it seems to be still here?! So now my question is:

Does Golang have some problem to recompile some file?

#-------------------------------------

Workspace

```
pkg

    linux_amd64

src

   algo  database_sql  github.com  golang.org  GoogleAPI  googlemaps.github.io  main  main.go  models  myDebug  router  server
```

I'm making "go build main.go"

I also read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) without find any solution...

Some hints?

Comment: If you want help update your question to post the minimum code to re-create the issue ... otherwise its hard to guess

Comment: go build filename.go only builds that one file, and doesn't look at your other files.   Normally, you just want to do "go install" from the project dir and have it "just work(tm)" and install to $GOPATH/bin.  but if you really want to build a set of files, list all of them on the command line, like go build *.go  (but this is a bad habit to get in to)

Comment: I'm not ok with you David, if I do "go build main.go" and in this file.go, I added an import such as algo, it will compiles both, I'm doing that from the begining of my using of golang

Comment: @MaximeGuittet David is right in that go build main.go, only instructs the compiler to build one file. So it might be using the same binary of server.go each time that you build main. Because you are not telling it to do so.

Comment: So you mean, if I understood, if I compile only one file which import another package, the package isn't compiled too? I mean I can't use a function in package algo from main by example?

Comment: it is specific to a go version. Not provided in this old post. Does not worth kep this around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm guessing that your dev tree looks something like this:

```
src
├───algo
├───database_sql
├───github.com
├───golang.org
├───GoogleAPI
├───googlemaps.github.io
├───main
├───main.go
├───models
├───myDebug
├───router
└───server
    └───server.go
```

As you can see in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), you are supposed to have a folder for your project, so main.go should be `someproject/main.go` and you can then just use `go build` to build the entire project.

Ideally you will want to have all your projects in a folder for their web address, like `github.com/yourname/projectname`. I recommend you follow this convention even if a specific project is not going to be publicly accessible. I keep all my projects (even the ones that are not in github) in my `github/my user` folder. This way it's easier to find and classify all you software.

If you want to build a project and all of it's dependencies (in this case server/server.go) you can do `go build ./...`

You can also go into the server package and do  `go install` to install build and reinstall the package.

So you should have something like this:

```
GOPATH
├───bin
|   └───main (this will have the name of the folder)
├───pkg (this routes match the ones on src)
|   └───linux_amd64
|       └───server.a
└───src
    ├───algo
    ├───database_sql
    ├───github.com
    ├───golang.org
    ├───GoogleAPI
    ├───googlemaps.github.io
    ├───main
    |   └───main.go
    ├───models
    ├───myDebug
    ├───router
    └───server
        └───server.go
```

And then go to `src/main/` and do `go build ./...` to build all the dependencies. Ideally you will want to do `go install ./...` so that libraries are installed on the correct path, and your binaries also get created in the correct path and not in the `src` folder. If you do this, you will need to run the binary `bin/main`. I recommend that you add `GOPATH/bin` to your path so that you can install your software and just run it without going to the bin folder.

Probably there is some error in the way you are importing or using the server package. This is the best I can do without you posting your code.

**Edit:** After further thinking about this, I believe I found the error. You were doing `go build` to build the whole project, and at some point you did `go install` on the server library. So now `go build` is using the already compiled version of the library in `pkg`, so if you want to fix the problem do `go install` on the server file or `go install ./...` on the main folder.

This is not an error in Go, usually you don't want a change in a library to break your code, so you have to remember to install the new version of a library before trying your code.

Comment: Thank for you answer :) I didn't put code because it's not about the code, I think it's just about the file organization, because, I commented my code and it still compiles x) So It can't be about code, just maybe because some file aren't at the good place, like you explained, or because golang generated some temporary files :)

Comment: @MaximeGuittet I think I solve your problem. I edited the post.